# Suppose T is a tree with degree sequence 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3 plus several 2’s and 1’s. Find the number of leaves of T.

Tags: graph-theory, trees

> Suppose T is a tree with degree sequence 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3 plus several 2’s and 1’s. Find the number of leaves of T.

I currently have made this much progress. Let $x$ be the number of degree $2$ vertices and $y$ be the number of degree $1$ vertices (leaves). Then
$$|V| = 7 + x + y \implies |E| = 7 + x + y - 1 = 6 + x + y$$
and
$$2|E| = 5(3)+4(2)+3(2)+2(x)+1(y) \implies |E| = 29/2 + x + y/2$$
so $6 + x + y = 29/2 + x + y/2$, eventually you get $y = 17$.

But from here, I don't know how to get $x$. Do I have the right approach or is there something else I'm missing?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: This is a little unclear.  It seems like you're given the number of vertices and the number of edges.  Is this correct?

Comment: "Suppose T is a tree with degree sequence 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3 plus several 2’s and
1’s. Find the number of leaves of T." Is the entire question. From what I can tell, this doesn't tell us the number of vertices or number of edges.

Answer (score 3):

You are not missing anything.

All you needed to do is solve for the number of leaves, which is $y$ in your notation. The number of degree $2$ vertices, which is $x$, cannot be determined from this information alone - but you also don't need to know it to solve for the number of leaves.

In fact, you can construct a tree with degree sequence $5,5,5,4,4,3,3$ followed by $y=17$ ones, in there are no vertices of degree $2$. From there, you can take any edge and subdivide it into a path of arbitrary length, which will give you a tree with degree sequence $5,5,5,4,4,3,3$, followed by any number of twos you like, followed by $17$ ones. So there exist trees in which $x$ is any nonnegative integer you want it to be.

Comment: So what you're saying is that x is irrelevant to the problem? Is that because leaves cannot have deg of 2?

Comment: Right. Leaves are the vertices of degree $1$, and $y$ is the number of such vertices. $x$ is useful to set up the equations but irrelevant otherwise.

Comment: That makes a whole lot of sense! Thanks so much!